# Webkit transition not working on chrome with windows 8.1

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, windows-8.1

I'm implementing a themeforest template and having a weird issue with chrome on Win 8.1.

The CSS is using -webkit-transition to fade in divs. 
Weirdly, this is not working only on chrome and windows 8.1. 
Windows 7 or 8 with the same chrome version(latest), works just fine. also on ubuntu. 
On IE10, also perfectly.

Here is a [link](http://themeforest.net/item/gready-an-easy-to-use-app-and-landing-page/full_screen_preview/5635424) for the template preview.

Anyone has any idea?
Maby GPU issue?

Thanks, Roi.

Comment: I am on Windows 8 using Version 31.0.1650.48 m of Chrome and the header fades in just fine.

Comment: Not talking about the header, but the content of the page. Do you see the photos and videos?

Comment: Yes, The slide in from either side and fade in.

Comment: That's weird. I have tested it on two different laptops and the problem persists.

Comment: OK after validating more, the issue exsists only on windows 8.1.. Anyone got any clue?

Comment: @Roi Rav-Hon hey, I think I have the same issue that you do I have a website that works perfectly on most machine except for one laptop... I now tested your link it loads on my PC, but funny enough it does not work on this specific laptop. - This is the website I think I have a similar issue on - http://mordor.co.za/api/ those blocks should fade and be grey it works on the PC however it does not fade at all on this specific laptop. 

Do you think it is related?

Comment: @RoiRav-Hon sorry I did not tag you correctly in the previous comment.

Comment: Well @ErikThiart, its been 3 years now :) Not even holding this laptop anymore, so can't validate for you. Moved to Mac, and never looked back :)

Comment: Dammit wish I could figure out what the issue was/is.