# Chrome issue: Animation(transition) not working on all chrome installations

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a website which works on every machine I tested however on one particular laptop the animation does not work - I will attach two gifs that explains what I mean.

The one gif is on the laptop in question that the animation does not work on and the second gif with the grey is how the animation is suppose to work and works on my chrome and everyone I asked to test.

My question, what is the cause?

[image: Chrome that does not work]

[image: Chrome that works]

This I suspect is the same issue raised in this question:

[Webkit transition not working on chrome with windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936046/webkit-transition-not-working-on-chrome-with-windows-8-1)

But I am not sure.

--edit--

Both chromes on the machines are version 55 the latest ones that is what is baffling me. Everything seems identical yet on one machine this does not work. On that same machine it works in Firefox and Edge,but not in chrome or Opera

Comment: I think we'll need some code to have a look and see what's going on

Comment: I can do one better - here is the link to this site 

http://mordor.co.za/api/

Comment: What version of chrome do you have? (it's working for me chrome 55)

Comment: @AndrewBone Both are version 55 the latest ones that is what is baffling me. Everything seems identical yet on one machine this does not work.

On that same machine it works in Firefox and Edge,but not in chrome or Opera

Comment: try to use -webkit for css.
follow this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: @MarcoSantino He is using the webkit prefixes, starts around line 2592 of http://mordor.co.za/api/assets/css/main.css. Weird.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a CSS issue since that site will then not work on any of our chromes yet it only seems to not work on this one machine

Comment: The backgrounds in the first gif also look as if they have fewer colours. Is that an issue with the offending computer?

Comment: @MrLister Not at all, same colors, maybe the screenshot just did something odd. But the colors are the same.

Comment: Still no idea, what can cause this.